# Cookie Not Being Set On New Server

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have a site that's been running fine for months but since I moved to a new server a couple of weeks ago I've noticed some strange behavior.

I've tracked it down to the fact that the cookie is not being set.

Now the weird part is if I login to WordPress, which the site is built on, and then visit the page that should be setting the cookie, it works perfectly.

Does anybody have any ideas? I can't actually supply the link but the cookie setting code is simply...

```
setcookie($cookie_name,'is_set',time() + 3600*72, '/');// set cookie for 3 day
```

I think the fact that it works AFTER WordPress sets cookies but not before is a clue but I don't know the solution.

Thanks for your help

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out and will post the solution here just in case somebody else has the same issue.

The site was on a multisite install and I had the WP Super Cache plugin installed BUT NOT ACTIVATED on any of the sites.

Just it's mere presence was enough to screw up the cookie.

When I deleted the unused plugin everything worked as before.

Steve